# docker-compose is not detecting Postgres_password

Tags: postgresql, docker, flask, docker-compose

I have created a docker-compose.yml file where I specified two services. A flask api service and Postgres database service. I have also created a docker-compose.env file where I put my environment variables. But I keep getting an error when running docker-compose up which states that I didn't specify a superuser password for my postgres service:

Here is the error and the docker-compose.yml file:

```
Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
-superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".


version: "3.9"

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - docker-compose.env
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    networks:
      - ov_network
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=${DB_ENGINE}://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASSWORD}@db:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}

  db:
    build:
      context: ./database
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - docker-compose.env
    networks:
      - ov_network
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}

volumes:
  postgres_data:

networks:
  ov_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Is env file in the same directory as docker-compose? Please show it's content.